# MS Access weird numbers

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, double

I receive weird numbers from a function in VBA.

I have Continuous Forms where is a button from which user can manipulate sum of hours in a text box. This text box is located in Form Footer.

My code goes like this:

```
Private Sub Option39_Click()
    Dim time As Double

    'calculate time to format
    time = 25 / 24

    If Option39.Value = True Then
         Debug.Print dblTotal
        dblTotal = dblTotal + time
         Debug.Print dblTotal
        Me.txtTotalTeamTotal = FormatUnlimitedHours(dblTotal)
         Debug.Print dblTotal
    Else
        dblTotal = dblTotal - time
        Me.txtTotalTeamTotal = FormatUnlimitedHours(dblTotal)
    End If
End Sub
```

from debug.print i receive these values

```
3,66611111111111 
4,70777777777778 
112,986666666667
```

which I don't understand why the `dblTotal` change its value from `4,70777777777778 to 112,986666666667` Why was the number changed?

FormatUnlimitedHours() function is defined like this:

```
Public Function FormatUnlimitedHours(time As Variant) As Variant
    'function that can have unlimited number of hours in hh:mm:ss format
    Dim comma As Integer
    Dim hours As Variant
    Dim minutes As Variant
    'switch to hours format
    time = time * 24

    If time > 23 Then

        comma = InStr(time, ",") - 1

        If Not comma < 0 Then
            minutes = "0," & Mid(time, comma + 2, Len(time) - comma + 1)
            minutes = format(minutes / 24, "hh:mm:ss")
            hours = CDbl(Left(time, comma)) + CDbl(Left(minutes, InStr(minutes, ":") - 1))
            FormatUnlimitedHours = hours & ":" & Mid(minutes, InStr(minutes, ":") + 1, 5)
            Exit Function
        Else
            'for whole numbers
            FormatUnlimitedHours = time & ":00:00"
            Exit Function
        End If

    End If

    FormatUnlimitedHours = format(time / 24, "hh:mm:ss")

End Function
```

initial value of dblTotal is defined when the form is loaded

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    dblTotal = DSum("sumOfTotalTime", "QueryTime")

End Sub
```

Comment: By default, in VBA arguments are passed *by reference*, which means when you multiply `time` by 24, you're also affecting the value of `dblTotal` in the calling sub.

Comment: The point @Tim Williams makes is that passing an argument *ByVal*  creates a new, separate variable for use in the function to which it is given. `Function FormatUnlimitedHours(ByVal time As Variant)` would create such a variable by the name of `time`. If the method of transfer isn't specified *ByRef* is presumed, no duplicate is created, the function can change the value, and the new value will be available to the calling procedure. It's a very useful feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Tim Williams* has answered your question. However, you should never handle date and time as anything else than DateTime. It only complicates matters.

For example, comma is not the decimal separator in most English speaking countries, and the "base" type of DateTime is Double, so normally it makes no difference to convert back and forth between DateTime and Double.

Here's an example of a similar function following these rules - which also makes it a lot simpler:

```vb
Public Function FormatHourMinuteSecond( _
  ByVal datTime As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of days, hours, minutes, and seconds of datTime
' converted to hours, minutes, and seconds as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTime: #10:03:55# + #20:01:24#
'   returns: 30:05:19
'
' 2014-06-17. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinuteSec  As String
  Dim strHours      As String

  strHour = CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime))
  ' Add leading zero to minute and second count when needed.
  strMinuteSec = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2) & strSeparator & Right("0" & CStr(Second(datTime)), 2)
  strHours = strHour & strSeparator & strMinuteSec

  FormatHourMinuteSecond = strHours

End Function
```

Example:

```vb
? FormatHourMinuteSecond(25 / 24)
25:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)